# Adding check box to grid view for each row

Tags: asp.net

I am filling a `GridView` with the data table but on each row I want a check box how can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding checkbox to Gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664003/adding-checkbox-to-gridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="false" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Use this, you will find what you want!

Comment: Yeah! It will generate the check box column until the last row.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [< asp:TemplateColumn >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatecolumn(VS.71).aspx) or, depending on your desired functionality, opt for a [repeater control](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_repeater.asp) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the grid view and add a template column.  Inside that column, you are able to put whatever you want - including a checkbox.